# Docker-compose command doesn't override Dockerfile CMD

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

[Docker-compose reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) says:

> command
>
> Override the default command.

**My Dockerfile**

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/maven-openjdk8

RUN mkdir /config

COPY /src/main/resources/application.properties /config/application.properties
COPY /src/main/resources/logback.xml /config/logback.xml

# copy wait-for-it-sh tool to sync container starting
COPY wait-for-it.sh /
RUN chmod +x /wait-for-it.sh

VOLUME /tmp

ADD target/my-svc-1.jar app.jar

RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'

ENV JAVA_OPTS=""

CMD [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
```

**Interesting part of my docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  ..
  my-svc:
    container_name: my-svc-container
    build:
      context: ./my-svc-folder
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9100:9100"
      - "5005:5005"
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "my-svc-dbserver:3306", "--", "sh", "-c", "java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -jar /app.jar"]
  ...
```

Output of docker-compose build:

```
Building my-svc
Step 1/11 : FROM adoptopenjdk/maven-openjdk8
 ---> b3ad935008a1
Step 2/11 : RUN mkdir /config
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5db347c13050
Step 3/11 : COPY /src/main/resources/application.properties /config/application.properties
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ade3653a018a
Step 4/11 : COPY /src/main/resources/logback.xml /config/logback.xml
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 94277fd95be1
Step 5/11 : COPY wait-for-it.sh /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 80ac64c7c994
Step 6/11 : RUN chmod +x /wait-for-it.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1a0c99bc10ad
Step 7/11 : VOLUME /tmp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 81864f3c9fda
Step 8/11 : ADD target/my-svc-1.jar app.jar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 56cc5c149e37
Step 9/11 : RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9db3f5d983cc
Step 10/11 : ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a5c4828b6539
Step 11/11 : CMD [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cb1fd876d8d6
Successfully built cb1fd876d8d6
Successfully tagged src_my-svc:latest
```

So, the last step is shown as
`CMD [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]`, the one that is in Dockerfile instead of the one in docker-compose.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Overriding takes place at runtime, which is when you `create` a container based on an `image` and you then `start` it. That last step you see is during the `building` phase of the actual `image` which (correctly) follows the instructions of your `Dockerfile`.

So, if you continue with `docker-compose up`, the container that will be created and started, will have the "overridden" configuration provided in the `docker-compose.yaml` file.

---

From [Overriding Dockerfile image defaults](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#overriding-dockerfile-image-defaults)

> ### Overriding Dockerfile image defaults
>
> When a developer builds an image from a [*Dockerfile*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) or when she commits it, the developer can set a number of default parameters that take effect when the image starts up as a container.
> Four of the Dockerfile commands cannot be overridden at runtime: `FROM`, `MAINTAINER`, `RUN`, and `ADD`. **Everything else has a corresponding override in `docker run`.**

Comment: You are 100% right. And it works. But I could have sworn that I've been both building AND running the damn thing 20 times and it didn't work, it just used CMD from Dockerfile. And now it's working. Hm...

Comment: There are a lot of "gotchas" and I get confused sometimes too. Glad it worked!

Comment: IMPORTANT, I found I had to put the COMMAND-FULL-PATH, ie, command: ["/usr/local/bin/redis-server", "arg1", "arg2"] before this world work